# ExpressJs - How to make api files unreadable in developer tools

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

Naturally, when I use developer tools in Google and click open an API file in a new tab, I can see the data as exampled below.

But I have been to websites when I attempt to do the same thing, there is some security measure taken causing the opened in new tab page to show an "Unauthorized" message and not the data.

It cannot be a session event because I was logged in properly. I think it is determined by **WHAT** is calling the API file.

Does anyone know how to replicate this in my ExpressJs javascript/angularjs app?

```
{ 
   username: "James Doe",
   picture: "styles/person.png",
   activity: 12
}
```

[image]

**Here is an example from GTDNext.com**

[image]

Comment: And do you have an example of API's that do this? I don't think I've seen an API where the URL's can't be opened directly in the browser as long as the correct headers are sent

Comment: Refresh page and see above

Comment: have you checked whether there are special headers set on those requests?

Comment: Search for the implementation of HttpInterceptor in Angular and using Auth Token in the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the answer to this and I would like to share it with others because I think it is useful to add a layer of security on the client side when it comes to XHR data.

Keep in mind I am using angular.

In my app.config, I created 3 custom $httpProvider providers:

```
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put['X-Posted-By'] = 'mySecretApp'
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-Posted-By'] = 'mySecretApp'
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-By'] = 'mySecretApp'
```

In my node controller, that responds to the GET api call, I have this:

```
....
module.exports = {
  all: function (req, res) {
    if (req.header('x-requested-by') != "mySecretApp") {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: errMsg.Util_ErrorMsg.getErrorMessage('Invalid requester')
        });
    };
```

Now, if I retrieve the data properly, through the browser, I get the data. However, if I try to open the api straight out from the browser, no data appears.
Encrypting the data further would make it totally unreadable from 
developer tools -> Network -> XHR

Comment: Who are you trying to protect it from? Does your secret key change? Because it would be trivial to open up your page, dig through the JavaScript and find your secret key, and then issue a request with the needed headers. One could even automate it if need be.

Comment: He is just trying to protect it with low-level security that protects the API from unnecessary nuisance. 
For protecting the API from intruders, obviously this would look funny even to the intruder.